# Authenticate with AcquireTokenInteractive and use security key as default

Tags: c#, .net, azure-active-directory, microsoft-identity-platform

I have a C# program (Windows Application .NET 7.0) for logging in to Azure using Web Account Manager (WAM):

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var hwnd = this.Handle;
        var client_id = "....";
        var tenant_id = "....";

        var options = new BrokerOptions(BrokerOptions.OperatingSystems.Windows);
        var pca = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(client_id)
                .WithBroker(options)
                .Build();

        var authResult = pca.AcquireTokenInteractive(new[] { "User.Read" })
                                            .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, tenant_id)
                                            .WithParentActivityOrWindow(hwnd)
                                            .ExecuteAsync();
    }
```

This works fine but I would like to have "Sign in with a security key" as the default sign-in option. Currently I get a dialog where I can type in user name or choose "Sign-in options" and then choose security key. Is it possible to specify default sign-in option?